# why am i having trouble with CSS :focus selector?

Tags: css

I've created a CSS vertical submenu which works fine with the :hover selector to open the submenu's. However, when I try and change this to a :focus selector, it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? The code is purely CSS and there's no Javascript involved.

```css
nav ul {
 margin-top:1px; /* tucks the child ul up close to the parent li */
 border-color: blue;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 width: 150px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
nav li {
 list-style-type: none;
 border-color: aqua;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
}
nav ul li {
 display: none;
 border-color: lime;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 margin:1px;
 margin-top:-10px;
 margin-left:-10px;
}
nav {
 background-color: #c8b99c;  /* pale brown */
 width: 220px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
nav ul li.selected {
background-color: #c18946;
}
nav li a {  /* to make the whole box clickable, not just the link text */
 display:block; /* <<< this is the bit that does it */
 line-height:23px;
 text-decoration:none;
 border-color: red;
 border-width: 3px;
 border-style: solid;
}
nav li:hover ul li { 
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
 <title>My Webpage</title>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="nav_style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a>
   <ul>
   <li class="selected"><a href="#">Home</a>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 2</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a>
   <ul>
   <li class="selected"><a href="#">Home</a>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 2</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>   
 </nav>       
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Links and form element can take the focus , any other elements Will require a tabindex     attribute. Set it to tabindex="0" to avoid strange interaction if you use the tab key to navigate

Comment: An example  https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/gxcJj

Answer (score 1):

HTML element li does not receive focus. That is why :focus selector is not working on li elements.

You can fix this by adding tabindex attribute to the li element.

Example:

```css
nav ul {
 margin-top:1px; /* tucks the child ul up close to the parent li */
 border-color: blue;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 width: 150px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
nav li {
 list-style-type: none;
 border-color: aqua;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
}
nav ul li {
 display: none;
 border-color: lime;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 margin:1px;
 margin-top:-10px;
 margin-left:-10px;
}
nav {
 background-color: #c8b99c;  /* pale brown */
 width: 220px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
nav ul li.selected {
background-color: #c18946;
}
nav li a {  /* to make the whole box clickable, not just the link text */
 display:block; /* <<< this is the bit that does it */
 line-height:23px;
 text-decoration:none;
 border-color: red;
 border-width: 3px;
 border-style: solid;
}
nav li:hover ul li,nav li:focus ul li { 
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
 <title>My Webpage</title>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="nav_style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
   <li tabindex="0"><a href="#">Home</a>
   <ul>
   <li class="selected"><a href="#">Home</a>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 2</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li tabindex="0"><a href="#">Home</a>
   <ul>
   <li class="selected"><a href="#">Home</a>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Skeleton Page 2</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>   
 </nav>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Narayanan - that code did not it didn't work when i ran it.

Comment: I have updated my answer with code snippet. It should be working now.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. I want the menu to open when its in focus. Your code will only open it on hover. The tabindex is now bringing it into focus, I know this because I've tested it. However, the submenu fails to open on focus. It works though on hover. I don't get it. I'm completely bamboozled.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. I needed :focus-within, not :focus.